# Error en CSS al aplicar eventos a botones - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estoy realizando un visor de imágenes con cuatro botones (Primera, Anterior, Siguiente, Última).

De inicio se carga una imagen aleatoriamente (las tengo guardadas en una carpeta llamada "images"), y seguidamente nos podremos mover mediante eventos de esos cuatro botones.

¿Por qué no me aplica correctamente las modificaciones a los botones con relación al CSS?

```js
/*Al cargar la página realiza esta llamada a la funcion*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Creamos un objeto de la clase Galería. Le pasamos el parámetro necesario.
  galeria = new Galeria(7);
});

//Creamos la clase Galería con su método constructor, sus atributos y sus diferentes métodos necesarios.
var Galeria = function(imagenes) {
  //Indice de la imagen que se está mostrando (cursor).
  var cursor = 0;
  //Array con imágenes.
  var arrayImages = new Array();
  //Cantidad de imágenes.
  var numImages = imagenes; //7 imagenes de Juego de Tronos.
  //Añadimos las imagenes con un "for" al array "arrayImages".
  for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    arrayImages.push("foto" + i + ".jpg");
  }

  //Generamos un número aleatorio entre 1 y 7 y ese número se le asignamos al array "arrayImages".
  var imagenAleatoria = function() {
    cursor = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % imagenes;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la primera posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var primeraPosicion = function() {
    cursor = 0;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la última posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var ultimaPosicion = function() {
    cursor = arrayImages.length - 1;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion ANTERIOR a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionAnteriorActual = function() {
    if (cursor > 0) {
      cursor--;
      return arrayImages[cursor];
    } else {
      return arrayImages[0];
    }
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion SIGUIENTE a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionSiguienteActual = function() {
    if (cursor < 6) {
      cursor++;
      return arrayImages[cursor];
    } else {
      return arrayImages[6];
    }
  }


  //Comprobar donde está el cursor.
  var comprobarCursor = function() {
    if (cursor == 0) {
      $('#primera').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");

    } else if (cursor == 6) {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("deshabilitado");
    } else {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");
    }
  }

  //Inicialmente se cargará una imagen al azar.
  var inicializarImagen = function() {
    //En JS: document.getElementById("imagen").setAttribute("style", "background-image:.....");
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + imagenAleatoria() + ')'
    });
  }
  inicializarImagen();


  //Eventos de botones.
  $('#siguiente').click(function() {
    comprobarCursor();
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionSiguienteActual() + ')'
    });
  });

  $('#anterior').click(function() {
    comprobarCursor();
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionAnteriorActual() + ')'
    });
  });

  $('#primera').click(function() {
    comprobarCursor();
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + primeraPosicion() + ')'
    });
  });

  $('#ultima').click(function() {
    comprobarCursor();
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + primeraPosicion() + ')'
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: GoT;
  src: url("fonts/got.ttf");
}

* {
  font-family: GoT;
}


/* "Truco" para conseguir una imagen de fondo transparente en el body */

#contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

#contenedor:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(images/fondo.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#galeria {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#imagen {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-image 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s;
}

#botones {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#botones ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#botones ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#botones * a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #B8B894;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3A;
  font-size: .6em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.deshabilitado {
  background-color: #FF5C33 !important;
}

.habilitado {
  background-color: #B8B894 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="galeria">
    <h2>Visor de personajes</h2>
    <div id="imagen"> </div>
    <div id="botones">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="primera">PRIMERA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="anterior">ANTERIOR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="siguiente">SIGUIENTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="ultima">ULTIMA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi error es que no asignan el CSS. Es decir: si cargo la página y tengo la foto1, el botón ANTERIOR o PRIMERA tienen que estar en color naranja, entiendo que están deshabilitados, y si voy avanzando foto a foto mediante el botón SIGUIENTE, de la foto1 a la foto7, cuando llegue a la foto7 el botón SIGUIENTE y el botón última deben estar deshabilitados.

Comment: Creo que no se ve la ejecucción correctamente debido a que tengo incluido la librería jQuery por eso no detecta el símbolo dollar "$".

Comment: Le puse un alert a todos tus botones y si funcionan cual es tu error'

Comment: Mi error es que no asignan el css. Es decir: si cargo la página y tengo la foto1, el boton ANTERIOR o PRIMERA tienen que estar en color naranja, entiendo que están deshabilitados, y si voy avanzando foto a foto mediante el boton siguiente... siguiente...siguiente... de la foto1 a la foto7, cuando llegue a la foto7 el boton siguiente y el boton ultima deben estar deshabilitados.

Answer (score 1):

**El problema es que estás añadiendo las clases "habilitado" y "deshabilitado" sin quitar la que no corresponda**. Entonces, al final los botones acabarán teniendo ambas clases y la clase "habilitado" tiene mayor precedencia y es la que se aplicará sobre la clase "deshabilitado":

```
.deshabilitado {
  background-color: #FF5C33 !important;
}

.habilitado {
  background-color: #B8B894 !important;
}
```

Una solución rápida sería quitar las dos clases "habilitado" y "deshabilitado" al principio del método `comprobarCursor`. Esto se puede hacer en jQuery con una sola línea usando el método `removeClass`:

```
$("#botones a").removeClass("habilitado deshabilitado");
```

Además se llama a `comprobarCursor` antes de actualizar el valor de `cursor` en `posicionSiguienteActual` y por eso siempre se va a ir uno detrás de lo que debería. Cambia el orden y problema solucionado, por ejemplo:

```
  $('#anterior').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionAnteriorActual() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });
```

Y por último, se llama a `primeraPosicion` en lugar de `ultimaPosicion` cuando se pulsa en el botón ULTIMO.

Con todos esos cambios, el código ya funciona bien y se ve así:

```js
/*Al cargar la página realiza esta llamada a la funcion*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Creamos un objeto de la clase Galería. Le pasamos el parámetro necesario.
  galeria = new Galeria(7);
});

//Creamos la clase Galería con su método constructor, sus atributos y sus diferentes métodos necesarios.
var Galeria = function(imagenes) {
  //Indice de la imagen que se está mostrando (cursor).
  var cursor = 0;
  //Array con imágenes.
  var arrayImages = new Array();
  //Cantidad de imágenes.
  var numImages = imagenes; //7 imagenes de Juego de Tronos.
  //Añadimos las imagenes con un "for" al array "arrayImages".
  for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    arrayImages.push("foto" + i + ".jpg");
  }

  //Generamos un número aleatorio entre 1 y 7 y ese número se le asignamos al array "arrayImages".
  var imagenAleatoria = function() {
    cursor = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % imagenes;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la primera posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var primeraPosicion = function() {
    cursor = 0;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la última posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var ultimaPosicion = function() {
    cursor = arrayImages.length - 1;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion ANTERIOR a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionAnteriorActual = function() {
    if (cursor > 0) {
      cursor--;
      return arrayImages[cursor];
    } else {
      return arrayImages[0];
    }
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion SIGUIENTE a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionSiguienteActual = function() {
    if (cursor < 6) {
      cursor++;
      return arrayImages[cursor];
    } else {
      return arrayImages[6];
    }
  }


  //Comprobar donde está el cursor.
  var comprobarCursor = function() {
    $("#botones a").removeClass("habilitado deshabilitado");
console.log(cursor);
    if (cursor == 0) {
      $('#primera').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");

    } else if (cursor == 6) {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("deshabilitado");
    } else {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");
    }
  }

  //Inicialmente se cargará una imagen al azar.
  var inicializarImagen = function() {
    //En JS: document.getElementById("imagen").setAttribute("style", "background-image:.....");
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + imagenAleatoria() + ')'
    });
  }
  inicializarImagen();


  //Eventos de botones.
  $('#siguiente').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionSiguienteActual() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  $('#anterior').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionAnteriorActual() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  $('#primera').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + primeraPosicion() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  $('#ultima').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + ultimaPosicion() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: GoT;
  src: url("fonts/got.ttf");
}

* {
  font-family: GoT;
}


/* "Truco" para conseguir una imagen de fondo transparente en el body */

#contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

#contenedor:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(images/fondo.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#galeria {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#imagen {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-image 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s;
}

#botones {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#botones ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#botones ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#botones * a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #B8B894;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3A;
  font-size: .6em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.deshabilitado {
  background-color: #FF5C33 !important;
}

.habilitado {
  background-color: #B8B894 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="galeria">
    <h2>Visor de personajes</h2>
    <div id="imagen"> </div>
    <div id="botones">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="primera">PRIMERA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="anterior">ANTERIOR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="siguiente">SIGUIENTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="ultima">ULTIMA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación del "removeClass()". Funciona, pero el problema lo sigo teniendo: ¿por qué si retrocedo hasta la imagen 1, cuando estoy en la imagen2, pulso Anterior (sería la imagen1, osea la primera) entonces Primera y Anterior deberían deshabilitarse, y no lo hacen hasta que vuelvo a hacer otro click en "Anterior".

Comment: @omaza1990 parece que el problema es que llamas a `comprobarCursor` antes de actualizar el valor de `cursor` en `posicionSiguienteActual` y por eso siempre vas uno detrás de lo que debieras.

Comment: Perfecto, aquí estaba mi duda.

Comment: Además, hay otros problemas: cuando le das a ULTIMO, llamas a `primeraPosicion` en lugar de `ultimaPosicion`

Comment: Ya he añadido esos cambios y ahora ya funciona bien.

Comment: Eso lo arreglé, lo tenía mal. Sí, cierto, me di cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

en tu código se produce una paradoja ya que no se lo que quieres hacer, si es: crear una instancia del objeto `galerias`, o bien: crear una función donde defines variables `globales`.

Ahora dicho esto colocare los 2 ejemplos de las posibles soluciones:

**Primera opción**: Creando una instancia del objeto **galerias**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Creamos un objeto de la clase Galería. Le pasamos el parámetro necesario.
  galeria = new Galeria(7);
});

//Creamos la clase Galería con su método constructor, sus atributos y sus diferentes métodos necesarios.
var Galeria = function(imagenes) {
  //Indice de la imagen que se está mostrando (cursor).
  var this.cursor = 0;
  //Array con imágenes.
  var this.arrayImages = new Array();
  //Cantidad de imágenes.
  var this.numImages = imagenes; //7 imagenes de Juego de Tronos.
  //Añadimos las imagenes con un "for" al array "arrayImages".
  for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    this.arrayImages.push("foto" + i + ".jpg");
  }
```

Así deberías manejar el objeto **galerias**:
(**NOTA**: este ejemplo aplica a todo el código donde manejes el objeto **galerias**)

```
  //Generamos un número aleatorio entre 1 y 7 y ese número se le asignamos al array "arrayImages".
  var imagenAleatoria = function() {
    galeria.cursor = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % galeria.numImages;
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }
```

**Segunda opción**: Creando una funcion para manejar variables **Globales**:

```
//Creamos la clase Galería con su método constructor, sus atributos y sus diferentes métodos necesarios.
var Galeria = function(imagenes) {
  //Indice de la imagen que se está mostrando (cursor).
  cursor = 0;
  //Array con imágenes.
  arrayImages = new Array();
  //Cantidad de imágenes.
  numImages = imagenes; //7 imagenes de Juego de Tronos.
  //Añadimos las imagenes con un "for" al array "arrayImages".
  for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    arrayImages.push("foto" + i + ".jpg");
  }
```

Así deberías manejar las variables **Globales**:

```
  //Generamos un número aleatorio entre 1 y 7 y ese número se le asignamos al array "arrayImages".
  var imagenAleatoria = function() {
    cursor = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % imagenes;
    return arrayImages[cursor];
  }
```

Yo sugiero utilizar la primera opción pero quedara de tu parte optar por la que mas te gustes, Saludos!! ;))...

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional utilizando la **Primera Opción**:

```js
//Creamos la clase Galería con su método constructor, sus atributos y sus diferentes métodos necesarios.
var Galeria = function(imagenes) {
  //Indice de la imagen que se está mostrando (cursor).
   this.cursor = 0;
  //Array con imágenes.
   this.arrayImages = new Array();
  //Cantidad de imágenes.
   this.numImages = imagenes; //7 imagenes de Juego de Tronos.
  //Añadimos las imagenes con un "for" al array "arrayImages".
  for (var i = 1; i <= imagenes; i++)
    this.arrayImages.push("foto" + i + ".jpg");
}

  //Generamos un número aleatorio entre 1 y 7 y ese número se le asignamos al array "arrayImages".
  var imagenAleatoria = function() {
    galeria.cursor = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100)) % galeria.numImages;
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la primera posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var primeraPosicion = function() {
    galeria.cursor = 0;
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la última posición del array, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var ultimaPosicion = function() {
    galeria.cursor = galeria.arrayImages.length - 1;
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion ANTERIOR a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionAnteriorActual = function() {
    galeria.cursor--;
    if (galeria.cursor < 0) {
      galeria.cursor = 6;
    }
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }

  //Cursor en la posicion SIGUIENTE a la actual, devolviendo el nombre de la imagen que hay en la misma.
  var posicionSiguienteActual = function() {
    galeria.cursor++;
    if (galeria.cursor > 6) {
      galeria.cursor = 0;
    }
    return galeria.arrayImages[galeria.cursor];
  }


  //Comprobar donde está el cursor.
  var comprobarCursor = function() {alert(galeria.cursor);
      $('#primera').removeClass("deshabilitado habilitado");
      $('#anterior').removeClass("deshabilitado habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').removeClass("deshabilitado habilitado");
      $('#ultima').removeClass("deshabilitado habilitado");

    if (galeria.cursor == 0) {
      $('#primera').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");

    } else if (galeria.cursor == 6) {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("deshabilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("deshabilitado");
    } else {
      $('#primera').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#anterior').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#siguiente').addClass("habilitado");
      $('#ultima').addClass("habilitado");
    }
  }

  //Inicialmente se cargará una imagen al azar.
  var inicializarImagen = function() {
    //En JS: document.getElementById("imagen").setAttribute("style", "background-image:.....");
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + imagenAleatoria() + ')'
    });
  }
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Eventos de botones.
  $('#siguiente').click(function() {
    comprobarCursor();
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionSiguienteActual() + ')'
    });
  });

  $('#anterior').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + posicionAnteriorActual() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  $('#primera').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + primeraPosicion() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  $('#ultima').click(function() {
    $('#imagen').css({
      'background-image': 'url(images/' + ultimaPosicion() + ')'
    });
    comprobarCursor();
  });

  //Creamos un objeto de la clase Galería. Le pasamos el parámetro necesario.
  galeria = new Galeria(7);

  inicializarImagen();
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: GoT;
  src: url("fonts/got.ttf");
}

* {
  font-family: GoT;
}


/* "Truco" para conseguir una imagen de fondo transparente en el body */

#contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

#contenedor:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(images/fondo.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#galeria {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#imagen {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background-image 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s;
}

#botones {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#botones ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#botones ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#botones * a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #B8B894;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3A;
  font-size: .6em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.deshabilitado {
  background-color: #FF5C33 !important;
}

.habilitado {
  background-color: #B8B894 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="galeria">
    <h2>Visor de personajes</h2>
    <div id="imagen"> </div>
    <div id="botones">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="primera">PRIMERA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="anterior">ANTERIOR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="siguiente">SIGUIENTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="ultima">ULTIMA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @fwBasic, pero esto no es dónde está mi gran duda.

Comment: que te puedo decir, si a ti la respuesta que te acabo de dar te parece poco problema que tienes en tu código, como poder encontrar el verdadero problema de tu "gran duda".

Comment: Lo que quiero es crear un instancia/objeto de la clase Galeria, y creo si estamos dentro del mismo documento o mismo .js, no hace falta hacer referencia a "nombreClase.atributo o nombreClase.metodo", ¿qué es más legible y entendible? Creo que sí.

Comment: hay dos formas de trabajar: creando una instancia o trabajando con variables globales, cualquier otra caso es un invento el cual no comparto, estas haciendo una mezcla de ambos y lo que haces es confundir, te deje un ejemplo funcional partiendo del código que publicaste pero que tuve que hacer muchos cambios para que funcionara, definitivamente cada quien tiene su lógica de programar, espero esto te sirva para entender donde están los problemas en tu código, Saludos!! ;))....